# Installation Exchange 2016 IIS starts too many processes

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, exchange-2016

I'm trying to install Exchange 2016 on my Windows Server 2016.

I'm getting the error that there is too less RAM:
[image]

So I checked and I saw that the RAM is at 94%. My machine has 8GB, so this should be enough. The problem is, that IIS starts a lot of worker-processes (30-40 processes).

(We already had installed Exchange on that server, and it worked, but we had to reinstall the server.)

I tried a restart, also shot a "iisreset" but that doesn't help: RAM decreases to 64% after iisreset and on start it increases up to 94% again..

Any idea whatthe real problem could be?

Comment: Which Exchange version are you using (CU level). You should use the latest CU ISO here which is more a full installation. I saw which issues as well in the past and this was caused by a bug which is / was solved with the a CU. So you really should check if you are using the latest one.

Comment: @BastianW I'm using CU8 - should be the latest. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is looking at the Exchange Setup Log, which should be located at the root of the drive you are trying to install Exchange on. Whenever I'm installing Exchange, I like to have that open in the CMTrace tool at the same time. The CMTrace tool does "tailing," which means that it updates the console as Exchange writes to the log. Perhaps it's trying to accomplish a task and it can't, so it creates another IIS process without properly killing a previous task.